# What does "Works" of Ontario Works mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I live in the province of Ontario in Canada. The ministry of community and social services here have a type of welfare called *[Ontario Works](http://www.mcss.gov.on.ca/en/mcss/programs/social/ow/)*, and this provides financial and employment assistance to individuals in need. And I'm wondering, what does *Works* of *Ontario Works* mean? I've looked up the term in the dictionaries, but couldn't find anything relevant to the context.

Comment: It's a pun on *Works*, as *Public Works*, and on *works* as *earning a living*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the third person singular present of the verb "to work." There's nothing deeper than that; this is a baroque rat's idea of a fun, modern name for the programme.

Comment: To be eligible for the program you must be able to work, agree to "take part in activities that will help you find a job" and so on. This is in contrast to someone who cannot work (because they are disabled perhaps). The name of the program describes their hope for what it will achieve - to transition people from needing financial aid to working. (As for whether it meets that goal, or whether being on it is as fun and upbeat as the name, that's a different story.)

Comment: btw @James, is baroque rat a deliberate pun?

Comment: LOL yes, although I expect someone to correct it. (I can't claim credit for it - I read it in a sci-fi story during the eighties - whose name I forgot long ago.) Or maybe I should say - you live here, you tell me?

Answer (score 3):

[Public works](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/public-works?q=public%20works) is a common phrase for such things as building new hospitals, and I imagine some bureaucrat could not resist the play on words between this (which historically involved work for local unemployed labourers, though less so nowadays), and a slogan about 'getting Ontario back to work'. As a bonus, it implies that the Ontario administration is working well. Clever, eh? (at least by political standards.)